# XJC is generating wrong namespace in package-info.java

Tags: java, xml, maven, xsd, xjc

the approach is to generate java classes by xsd using jaxb2-maven-plugin.

The pom:

```
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
            <artifactId>jaxb2-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>1.5</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>xjc</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
            <configuration>
                <packageName>${project.groupId}.model</packageName>
                <extension>true</extension>
                <arguments>-b ${resource.dir}/jaxbbindings.xsd -Xannotate</arguments>
                <outputDirectory>${basedir}/src/main/java</outputDirectory>
                <schemaFiles>1.0.xsd</schemaFiles>
                <clearOutputDir>true</clearOutputDir>
            </configuration>
            <dependencies>
                <dependency>
                    <groupId>org.jvnet.jaxb2_commons</groupId>
                    <artifactId>jaxb2-basics-annotate</artifactId>
                    <version>0.6.4</version>
                </dependency>
                <dependency>
                    <groupId>com.sun.codemodel</groupId>
                    <artifactId>codemodel</artifactId>
                    <version>2.6</version>
                </dependency>
                <dependency>
                    <groupId>javax.persistence</groupId>
                    <artifactId>persistence-api</artifactId>
                    <version>1.0.2</version>
                </dependency>
            </dependencies>
        </plugin>
```

And the xsd 1.0:

```
<xs:schema
 targetNamespace="http://example.com/1.0"
 xmlns:gs="http://example.com/1.0"
 xmlns:cmn="http://example.com/another"
 xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
   <xs:import schemaLocation="another.xsd"
   namespace="http://example.com/another" />
   ....
 </xs:schema>
```

As you can seen with the import tag I intend to import another schema.

another.xsd:

```
<xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
 elementFormDefault="qualified"
 targetNamespace="http://example.com/another"
 xmlns:vt="http://example.com/another">
  ...
</xs:schema>
```

So, if maven executes XJC to generate the java classes by XSD, the package-info is also generated:

```
@javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlSchema(namespace = "http://example.com/another")
package de.fraunhofer.fokus.testing.fokusmbt.specexplorer.model;
```

As you can seen above the namespace is http://example.com/another. But this is wrong. The namespace should be http://example.com/1.0.

The another stuff works fine (generating java classes and so on).

What do I wrong?

Comment: have you solved this issue? if yes, how did you solve it?

Answer (score 2):

you generate 2 set of classes **1#** http://example.com/another **2#** http://example.com/1.0. For each set of classes will be generated `package-info.java`, but you override a generation folder in `"${project.groupId}.model"` so you have one `package-info.java` that define only one namespace.

You should remove `<packageName>${project.groupId}.model</packageName>` and all works fine.

Comment: @SvenW. It was a pleasure to help you :) mark this topic as resolved.